# VBA : Using a function to set a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I use really often that routine that I wanted to modify into a function to be able to set the added sheet right away, like this

```
Set ShP = DeleteAndAddSheet("Name")
```

So here is the function :

```
Public Function DeleteAndAddSheet(ByVal SheetName As String) As Worksheet

For Each aShe In Sheets
    If aShe.Name <> SheetName Then
    Else
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        aShe.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next aShe

Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = SheetName

DeleteAndAddSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

End Function
```

I get an error '91' on last row when setting the function's output, "Object variable or With variable is not set"

I tried with Sheets and Worksheets and neither one of them work...

Any idea?

Comment: It says that it is a syntax error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
DeleteAndAddSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

to

```
set DeleteAndAddSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

Comment: The syntax you are providing is correct. My question is: *Is it possible for function to return a `Worksheet object`?*

Comment: Awesome! Thx!
Can't accept the answer for 3 minutes, don't know why but will do ;)

Comment: Functions can return objects in general.

Comment: As evidenced by R3uK's response. :) They wouldn't be particularly useful if they couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You neeed to make it into a `Sub` instead, a `Function` cannot change anything apart from the cell it is working on, so the `Application.DisplayAlert`-statements, as well as the attempt to delete a worksheet causes it to throw an error.

Upon some testing, it appears that a `function` will let you e.g. delete a sheet, but it will not let change application-settings.

Comment: He indicated that the error is on the last line of code. So unless it's failing to make it into the `If` statement, I'm not sure that's the issue.

Comment: For what I know it's true, the formula modifies the hosting cell, that can clearly not store a Worksheet object. If you really want this to be done by a function, you're free to add/remove sheets in the body of the function but you need to return another type of value (a boolean True/False for example)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ "the formula modifies the hosting cell" in general or in this particular case? His code isn't modifying any cells... There are some limitations on what a `Function` can do, but adding/deleting worksheets and returning an object are _not_ among those limitations. (Note, he's posted that my suggested fix is working for him, and has accepted that as an answer). Not trying to be harsh, just trying to help out.

Comment: A Function is limited **when called from a cell** - I do not think that is the case here.

Comment: @FreeMan no worries, it's important to discuss (everyone has something to learn). I'd be curious to see if you get a `#Value` error in the cell from which you call the function; in that case, is not the function which is returning the worksheet, it's added just because the command to do it is embedded in the function body (as it would be in a macro). But I thought we were discussing about the _return_ of the function, in that case you will see yourself that you can return whatever (an empty `String`, a `Boolean` etc. and still have the worksheet added/removed ;)

Comment: @FreeMan I was replying in the assumption that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207513/how-to-prevent-excel-from-crashing-when-renaming-a-sheet-in-a-workbook-with-udfs/29209503#29209503) I got a couple of days ago was correct for all functions, but apparently the functions aren't quite as fragile when they are not volatile. I still kinda agrees with the premise posted in that answer though, "you use functions to calculate - you subs to change things."

Comment: P.s. just to make clear: in this case the user wants to use a function just because he doesn't want to press "execute" on the macro (or adding a shortcut to it), but functions are done for returning an output (not only in VBA) and in this specific case the function is not returning anything used, but just trying to cast a worksheet in a cell (clearly getting a value error). For elegance's sake, I would have rather returned a Boolean to confirm the correct execution of the Sub code embedded in the function.

Comment: Interesting. You guys, (@MatteoNNZ & eirikdaude) seem to be assuming he'll be calling this function by putting it in a cell with `=DeleteAndAddSheet(something)` that's not an assumption that I made at all. I just assumed it was a subroutine in his VBA code and he wanted to make it a function so he could return the new sheet and make his code a little cleaner. From your perspective, I believe you're correct. I just hadn't thought of it from that angle at all. (I believe Rory hit on that 20 minutes ago...)

Comment: @FreeMan reading properly the question, I see he starts with a sample use of the function that is in-code (within VBA) and not out-of-code (in Excel); I've stuck on "I use it so often.." and didn't pay the right attention. In this case, you're absolutely right: functions within the code are _absolutely done_ for returning objects.